# String command for admins only [ php ]

Tags: php

I have a small site that contains anonymous messages from people, and I want if I write a command, for example /admin, before my speech, my color appears in red, and before my words I appear as an admin
Example

/admin Hello

Admin: hello

```
$word = "Admin";

if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if(strpos($row["post_title"], $word) !== false){
        printf ("
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                    <div class='testimonial'>
                        <div class='pic'>
                            <img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/94/94386.png'>
                        </div>
                        <p class='description' style='color:red'>" . $row["post_title"] . " </p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>");
        }
        
    else{
                printf ("
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                    <div class='testimonial'>
                        <div class='pic'>
                            <img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/94/94386.png'>
                        </div>
                        <p class='description'>Anonymous: " . $row["post_title"] . " </p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>");
    }
```

Comment: Have you thought about using preg_match? ( if(preg_match('/admin'/, $admin)){$color = "red";}else{$color: "white"; ) And then use inline css with the $color. This way you can ask if the user is a member and make it yellow and a guest white

Comment: @Namys Thank you very much for this example but how can I check if I am an admin or not

Comment: You can use SESSIONS if you have a login, make in the database an extra column for admin, make it a bit(yes/no) and ask in php with a querry if the recieved user is admin, based on that you can use $_SESSION['admin'] = "true"; then you ask in this script if the user is admin if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){ 'define $color'}

Comment: @Namys Dude you saved me, Thanks!